# How are the randomizer values on the Apple II maintained?

Tags: apple-ii, applesoft-basic

Looking at a comment on [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26117/which-version-of-basic-uses-random-for-seeding-the-rng), it reminded me of how there are two memory locations in the Apple II zero page that are used for random number generation: 0x4E and 0x4F (78 and 79, respectively).

How are the values in this field maintained so that it is always able to help produce a somewhat useful random number seed? Is it ticked or mathematically changed as part of an GETCH / keyboard input call, or is it manipulated during some other blocking call?

Comment: Remember that RND is basically broken. Bob Sander-Cederlof created a replacement that can be called from Basic linked in my answer [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/19786/71). See Fadden's answer (and my comment) to understand why RND is broken.

Comment: @NickWestgate: those answers appear to be talking about Applesoft's RND function, which is completely independent of the ROM RNDL/RNDH values.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's incremented while waiting for keyboard input.

The 16-bit random seed (`RNDL` and `RNDH`) is updated by the `KEYIN` routine as it spins while waiting for a key press.  `KEYIN` is used by the Monitor ROM's keyboard input routines like `GETLN` and `RDKEY`.

[Apple II+ Monitor ROM Listing](https://6502disassembly.com/a2-rom/OrigF8ROM.html#SymKEYIN):

```
fd1b: e6 4e        KEYIN       inc     RNDL
fd1d: d0 02                    bne     KEYIN2          ;incr rnd number
fd1f: e6 4f                    inc     RNDH
fd21: 2c 00 c0     KEYIN2      bit     IOADR           ;key down?
fd24: 10 f5                    bpl     KEYIN           ;  loop
fd26: 91 28                    sta     (BASL),y        ;replace flashing screen
fd28: ad 00 c0                 lda     IOADR           ;get keycode
fd2b: 2c 10 c0                 bit     KBDSTRB         ;clr key strobe
fd2e: 60                       rts
```

Comment: Great first answer. Welcome to the site!